# Derivative of a function of two variables wrt another function of the two variables

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, derivatives

I want to compute the following derivative

$$
\frac{d}{d(x+y)^2}xy\,.
$$

To do it I change variables
$$
x+y\equiv \sqrt{2}u\quad\text{and}\quad x-y\equiv \sqrt{2}v\,, \qquad\text{so that}\qquad u+v= \sqrt{2}x\quad\text{and}\quad u-v=\sqrt{2}y\,,
$$
to rewrite the derivative as
$$
\frac{d}{d\left(\sqrt{2}u\right)^2}\frac{1}{2}\left(u^2-v^2\right)=\frac{1}{4}\,.
$$

I have two questions:

1. Is the derivative well defined?
2. Does the procedure (and the result) make sense?

Comment: No matter how you transform the variables, $xy$ is not a function of $(x+y)^2\,.$ The answers are therefore no and no.

Comment: Are you saying that the result of the derivative is zero or it is not even defined? In the second case why it is so? Intuitively if I change $x+y$ the function $xy$ changes in some way, right?

Comment: A total derivative of the form $\frac{df}{dg}$ can be viewed as $$\frac{\;\frac{df}{dx}\;}{\;\frac{dg}{dx}\;}$$ but that's only defined when $f$ and $g$ are functions of $x$ only.

Comment: Ah, maybe is there a way to generalize it? I found the following question, which seems to be coherent with my "solution": https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/307411/derivative-of-fx-y-with-respect-to-another-function-of-two-variables-kx-y

Comment: Sorry, I should have checked for some answers before to post my question. I'll answer myself pointing at the previous link. Thanks anyway.

Comment: A partial derivative needs to know *what is being held constant* at all times. If I had a proper coordinate change of $u=xy$ and $v=(x+y)^2$, then your derivative would be $\frac{\partial u}{\partial v}= 0$ for any pair of independent coordinates. On the other hand if I chose $u=x^2+y^2$, then your derivative would be $$\frac{\partial\left(\frac{v-u}{2}\right)}{\partial v} = \frac{1}{2}$$ You always need specify all of your variables, aka the full change of coordinates.

Comment: The mapping between $(x,y)$ and $(u,v)$ should be invertible, no doubt that if you use these (non-invertible) mappings the derivative changes.

Comment: @RuthMurphy your comment has no bearing on the point I was making. Of course all coordinate changes are invertible or have a domain of invertibility. The point is you do not have enough information to specify a partial derivative without a specifying a mapping from a full set of $n$ variables to another set of $n$ variables. There is no such thing as a canonical change of variables to enforce that unrigorous notation as you have attempted to do in the latest edit of your post.

Answer (score 1):

The derivative can be defined as the derivative of a function of two variables, $f(x,y)=xy$, with respect to another function of two variables, $g(x,y)=(x+y)^2$. The simple change of variables gives the correct answer, for a rigorous explanation check the following question: [Derivative of $f(x,y)$ with respect to another function of two variables $k(x,y)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/307411/derivative-of-fx-y-with-respect-to-another-function-of-two-variables-kx-y) .

Comment: The accepted answer to the linked question is quite misleading! See Qiaochu Yuan's answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3353862/differentiation-of-one-function-with-respect-to-another-in-multivariable-calculu) instead.

Answer (score 0):

The expression
$$
\frac{d}{d(x+y)^2}xy
$$
is *undefined* as a total derivative of a function $f(x,y)=xy$ with respect to another function $g(x,y)=(x+y)^2\,.$ The case when
$$
\frac{df}{dg}
$$ is defined is precisely when the two functions can be rewritten as functions of a single common variable $t\,.$  If this is the case can be tested with each of the following necessary conditions:

- locally $f$ is a function of $g$ and vice versa
- the two functions share the same level sets: $\{(x,y):f(x,y)=c\}=\{(x,y):g(x,y)=c'\}$
- $df\wedge dg\equiv 0\,.$ See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4673568/what-does-df-wedge-dg-0-imply/4774869#4774869) for a proof.

Plotting $xy$ and $(x+y)^2$ in GeoGebra or Desmos should immediately convince you that they don't have the same level sets.

Also: $df=x\,dy+y\,dx$ and $dg=2(x+y)(dx+dy)$ so that
$$
df\wedge dg=2x(x+y)\,dy\wedge dx+2y(x+y)\,dx\wedge dy=2(y^2-x^2)\,dx\wedge dy
$$
which does not vanish identically.